# My SPA files are giving 404 errors when serving the SPA in a branch of the request pipeline. How do I make my static files available to my SPA?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-page-application

First of, in my project root I have a folder called `ClientApp`, which contains a folder `build` which is where the output of my frontend build is located.

Then, in `Startup.cs`, I have the following in `ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
    });
}
```

Following, my `Configure` method looks as follows:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
     if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     } else {
         app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
         app.UseHsts();
     }

     app.UseHttpsRedirection();
     app.UseStaticFiles();
     app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
     app.UseAuthentication();

     app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

     app.Map("/dashboard", dashboard => {
         dashboard.Use(async (context, next) => {
             if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                 await next();
                 return;
             }

             context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
         });

         dashboard.UseSpa(spa => {
             spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

             if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                 spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

If I remove the `.Map(...)` and just serve the spa in on the `app` IApplicationBuilder instance, then it works.

Thank you in advance for any help, this has been bugging me for a few days now.

**Edit**
The setup I would want in the end is as follows. `/dashboard` would serve a SPA application, and anyone accessing that route has to be authenticated. However, routes such as `/Account/Login` would not be part of the SPA.

By moving `UseSpa` outside of the `Map`, any routes that are not handled by the Mvc or a static file in `wwwroot` will render the SPA, but when visiting e.g. `/about` I want to show a 404, not the SPA which renders the 404.

Answer (score 1):

For `app.Map`, it will route the request based on path `https://localhost:44378/dashboard/`. Which means only requests with `https://localhost:44378/dashboard/` will go into the `Spa` middleware.

For `dashboard.UseSpa`, it will survery spa static files with `https://localhost:44378/styles.bundle.css` which will not match `https://localhost:44378/dashboard/`.

If you did not want to change the request base path in SPA to `https://localhost:44378/dashboard/`, you may try move `UseSpa` outside of `app.Map("/dashboard"`.

```
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
        app.Map("/dashboard", dashboard =>
        {
            dashboard.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    await next();
                    return;
                }
                context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
            });
        });
```

**Update**

For changing **SPA Static files** request URL, you could try to change `package.json` like below:

```
"start": "ng serve --base-href=/dashboard/ --serve-path=/ --live-reload-client=https://localhost:port/frontend/sockjs-node/",
```

For another option while developing, change code below in `Startup`

```
        app.Map("/dashboard", frontendApp =>
        {
            frontendApp.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start --  --base-href=/frontend/ --serve-path=/ --live-reload-client=https://localhost:44302/frontend/sockjs-node/");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Moving `UseSpa` outside of `app.Map` will make the SPA available for all paths except for any MVC routes. That is not what I want though, since the "default" response should not be the client facing application (even with it displaying a 404) in my opinion. However, your explanation did clear up some things on how SpaServices operates so thank you for that.

Comment: For authentication and authorization for angular files, what about using [Route Guards](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3)? What sensitive information in `spa`? In general, static file are public access.

Comment: It is not about the access to the static files. What I mean is, if I take the `UseSpa` out of `Map`, then the spa will be accessible at any route which is not handled by the Mvc system. So `/dashboard` would go to the SPA, but `/about` would too, even if that page does not exist within my site. I'll edit the post to clarify what setup I have in mind.

Comment: Yes, this would have worked, except for the fact that my SPA is a react app using create-react-app instead of an Angular app using angular cli.

Comment: In order to make the angular server and live reloading work in development, include `app.useSpa(s => s.Options.SourcePath = null; if (env.IsDevelopment()) s.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");)`

Answer (score 1):

Right, after some clarification and help from Edward, I was able to identify the problem. As Edward pointed out, since the call to `UseSpa` was done inside a branch of the request pipeline, the static assets which are served at `ClientApp/build` are not used since the request for those assets starts with `/static/` and not `/dashboard`. This means the request pipeline is unaware of them.

The fix I found is actually more on the client build than the server, since I was unable to correctly let the server know about the static assets. The fix requires to set the `homepage` property in `package.json` as documented [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths). The only downside to this is that this does not work whilst running `npm start` since the build is not actually output to the filesystem but is instead in memory of the web-server.

On the server, I did have to move `app.UseSpaStaticFiles()` inside of the `Map` call in order for it to work correctly.

Thanks again to Edward for helping me better understand how `Map` works.