# asp.net core 3.1 with angular template can no longer respond with 404 and always redirect to spa index.html page

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, razor

I have an asp.net core 3.1 project with razor pages. I added a spa with angular with `<base href="/app" />` so that the app is server under `/app`. Now, any non existent route returns the spa index.html page instead of 404.

I don't have any client routing on my angular app.

My desired behavior is to respond with 404 if there is no route matching neither razor pages, the api, nor the `/app`.

However, when i type `localhost:5000/non-existent-route`, app redirects to my angular index.html app which is not the desired behavior.

Basically, i want to prevent the angular app's `index.html` from being the fallback default when no route is matched.

Here is my Startup.cs file

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => { options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; });
        services.AddSwaggerDocument();
        services.AddHealthChecks();
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => { configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist"; });
        // ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseOpenApi();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "api/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730535/my-spa-files-are-giving-404-errors-when-serving-the-spa-in-a-branch-of-the-reque. Which this question should be marked is duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do this on the server side, but it is possible on Angular side as below:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '', component: MainParentComponent, children: [
            { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent } //Default redirection for invalid URLs or unauthorised URLs
        ]
      }
    ])
  ]
})
```