# Angular handling MVC routes

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Angular SPA, with an ASP.NET Core Web API backend.

There is a backend serving not only the REST API endpoints. It also serves some MVC pages.

So for example,
https://myapp.com/superadmin only exists in the backend there is no such route in Angular routes.

However, when I put the URL in the browser address bar, Angular kicks in and says page not found (Angular is handling the route). When I hit the return key from the address bar again, it hits the MVC endpoint and loads the page.

So my question is: how can we tell Angular not to handle those MVC routes, and just let the browser load from remote?

Comment: Create a router that maps the desired white list of mvc routes. Send them all to the same component. In that component, take the url and do `window.location.href = target`. This should bypass the angular catches for url change. Not a solution to be proud of, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Please post your Configure method of Startup. You could also use `app.Map` to handle the path and redirect as you expected. The same issue seems to be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730535/my-spa-files-are-giving-404-errors-when-serving-the-spa-in-a-branch-of-the-reque).

Comment: Zze Thanks. I am now using your approach.
Michael Wang: I don't believe it's related to backend. It's because the SPA is cached in the browser, and when the url hits the browser, the SPA kicks in and tries to locate the route within the SPA, and the request does not go to backend.